# how to get x-axis,y-axis value of image while clicking on the image in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have tried to get (x-axis,y-axis)value of image while clicking on the image in tkinter in plone site.so whenever i click on the image i need to get the (x-axis,y-axis)value of image.The problem is that i can't able to get value.

I have created image dynamically on canvas in tkinter.so when i clicked the image,i need to get x-axis,y-axis value.I will explain my code deeply below.

```
class A(BrowserView):
   def B(event):
      x = event.x
      y = event.y
   def C(self):
      root = Tk()
      canvas = Canvas(width = 200, height = 250, bg = 'white')
      canvas.pack(expand = 'NO', fill = BOTH)
      gif1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = 'image1.png')
      D=canvas.create_image(50,50, image = gif1, anchor = NW)
      canvas.tag_bind(D, '<ButtonPress-1>',self.B()) #it will trigger the method B
      canvas.pack()
```

am getting the error like below

```
    AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 'x'
    x = event.x #get x-axis value
```

Help me to solve this problem.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition for `B` is missing the `self` parameter. You should code it like this:

```
def B(self, event):
    ...
```

You are also setting the binding wrong. When you create a binding you must give it a reference to a function. What you're doing is calling the function and giving the result of that function to the binding.

In other words, instead of this:

```
canvas.tag_bind(...,self.B())
```

You should be doing this:

```
canvas.tag_bind(...,self.B)
```

Comment: i can able to trigger that method.so that's not problem.. the problem is can't able to get x-axis,y-axis value..